# What is wrong with this proof there is no $\omega$-th worldly cardinal

Tags: fake-proofs

Call a cardinal $\kappa$ worldly iff $V_\kappa\vDash ZFC$. Let $\kappa_\alpha$ be the $\alpha$th worldly cardinal, i.e. the least worldly cardinal such that $\{\beta\lt\kappa_\alpha|\beta\text{ is worldly}\}$ has order-type $\alpha$. Since the class of worldly cardinals are closed, then $\kappa_\omega=\sup\kappa_n$.

Therefore, $V_{\kappa_\omega}\vDash\forall\alpha(\exists\delta\gt\alpha(V_\delta\vDash ZFC))$. Now define $f: \omega\rightarrow\kappa$ by $f(n)=\kappa_n$. We have that $f(n)$ is definable and absoloute to $V_{\kappa_\omega}$. Therefore, $f"\omega\in V_{\kappa_\omega}$ by the axiom of replacement. But this is impossible.